# Ucanaccess JDBC Driver - outofmemory error with memory=false setting

Tags: out-of-memory, ucanaccess, jackcess

I am using jackcess-2.1.1. I have set the memory=false parameter, but still face the outOfmemory Error. It happens while processing a MDB file of 1.8GB size.
The JVM memory arguments are set to 1GB max size. If I change the Max size to 2GB, it works with no issues.
But as per the instruction on the ucanaccess portal, when memory=false is set, then In-Memory is not supposed to be used and the JVM Memory Args should not change anything.

Any response is greatly appreciated. Find the error below.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.LongValueColumnImpl.readLongValue(LongValueColumnImpl.java:136)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.LongValueColumnImpl.read(LongValueColumnImpl.java:90)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.ColumnImpl.read(ColumnImpl.java:586)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.getRowColumn(TableImpl.java:767)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.getRow(TableImpl.java:673)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.getRow(TableImpl.java:652)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.CursorImpl.getCurrentRow(CursorImpl.java:699)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.CursorImpl$BaseIterator.next(CursorImpl.java:822)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.CursorImpl$BaseIterator.next(CursorImpl.java:1)
at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTableData(LoadJet.java:829)
at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTablesData(LoadJet.java:997)
at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTables(LoadJet.java:1041)
at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.access$2900(LoadJet.java:273)
at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.loadDB(LoadJet.java:1479)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:243)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1825)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1783)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I change the Max size to 2GB, it works with no issues. But as per the instruction on the ucanaccess portal, when memory=false is set, then In-Memory is not supposed to be used and the JVM Memory Args should not change anything.

That's not quite true. `memory=false` tells UCanAccess not to hold the HSQLDB backing database *tables* in memory, but a disk-based HSQLDB database will still consume *some* memory and there are lots of other things that UCanAccess (and Jackcess) must keep in memory too. The memory requirements with `memory=false` will just be considerably lower than with `memory=true`.